# How does append method works with while loop?

Tags: python

I tried to create a function that :
1.create a .txt file with a bunch of names from user's input.
2.then read the file and count how many names are there in the file.
3.then print out the names

Also I'm just a beginner so I may write something wrong here.

I've tried print out list_name everytime I enter the name. But it's not updated its value after the loop. Maybe I don't understand how does the while loop work here.

Please don't tell me exactly the code. I just want to understand how does the while loop works with append method here. Thanks you in advance.

```py
def create_listname(file_name = ' ') :
    while True:
        list_name = []
        name_input = str(input('''Enter \'stop\' if you are done.
        Please enter the name you want to list in : ''')) # Ask the name to record.
        if name_input == 'stop':
            break
        else:
            name_input + ' ' + '\n'
            list_name.append(name_input) # Add name to the list before turn to strings.
        name_liststr = ' '
        name_liststr = name_liststr.join(list_name)
    with open(file_name,'w') as name_list:
        name_list.write(name_liststr)
    return(file_name)

def read_text(file_name):
    with open(file_name,'r') as name_list:
        all_text = name_list.readline()
        print(all_text)
```

Comment: Try creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That will help us answer your question and likely help you fix it yourself!

Comment: @Ezra this already is minimal, how more minimal do You want it to be? on the other hand I guess it is a valid request tho in this case it seems to be debuggable from the given code

Comment: You're assigning an empty list to `list_name` inside the loop. That means each turn through the loop you're discarded whatever it was before and making it empty.

Comment: You've put `list_name = []` inside the loop, on each iteration it gets created anew and the old one is discarded.

Comment: As @Dimitry said, you arr overriding the list with a new one with each iteration

Comment: @Matiissits not bad, like a lot of code here- it just could be a little better. I left that mostly for you- a minimal example would have not had the read_text() definition, for example. Fewer lines makes it easier to spot the problem, which here is the list reassignment to empty. If the code was just say 5 lines it would have been obvious to you, so creating a minimal example is a good dev practice in general to solve problems.

Comment: oh! I see. I will try to create a minimal reproducible example as you mentioned next time. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

(I misunderstood earlier, so edited my answer)

You are reinitializing your `list_name` as well as `name_liststr` on each iteration of the while loop. look:

```
    while True:
        list_name = []
        ....
        ....
        name_liststr = ' '
        name_liststr = name_liststr.join(list_name)
```

This refreshes the list and the input added to this list in the previous iteration is gone. So just declare the list **outside** while loop.

```
def create_listname(file_name = ' ') :     
    list_name = []
    name_liststr = ' '
    while True:
        ....
        ....
        name_liststr = name_liststr.join(list_name)  
    with open(file_name,'w') as name_list:           
        name_list.write(name_liststr)
```

Comment: I understood. Thanks you so much !

Comment: @NOTMOE,  if it answers your query, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.